# Is this statement incorect?

Tags: intuition, proof-explanation

Taken from the introductory chapter of "How to Prove it A Structured Approach":

$(2^b - 1)(1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + ... + 2^{(a - 1)b}$

$=2^b(1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + ... + 2^{(a - 1)b}) - (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + ... + 2^{a - 1)b})$

$=(2^b + 2^{2b} + 2^{3b} + ... + 2^{ab}) - (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + ... + 2^{(a - 1)b})$

$=2^{ab} - 1$

A line 3 you take out all $2^b, 2^{2b}, 2^{3b}$ from the right side out of the left side and the only ones that remains are the $2^{ab}$ on the left side, the $-1$ on the right side and the $-2^{(a - 1)b}$ on the right side, so the final result should be:

$2^{ab} - 2^{(a - 1)b} - 1$

Shouldn't it?Yet the author removes the $2^{(a - 1)b}$ at the end of the right side, but how does he cancel it out?

Comment: Try it with $a=2, b=3$ and see which answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the result without ambiguity:

$$\left(2^b - 1\right)\left(1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + ... + 2^{(a - 1)b}\right)=\left(2^b - 1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}2^{bk}=\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}2^{b(k+1)}-\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}2^{bk}\\\underbrace{=}_{\text{change of index}}
\sum_{k=1}^{a}2^{bk}-\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}2^{bk}=2^{ab}-1$$

Comment: Could you explain how changing the range from $k=0$ -> $a-1$ to $k=1$ -> $a$ drop the $b$ from the exponent in $2^{b(k+1)}$, basically $2^{bk + b}$, to leave only $2^{bk}$?

Comment: If the range of $k$ is from $0$ to $a-1$ then the range of $m=k+1$ is from $1$ to $a$. Notice that I denoted again $m$ by $k$.